# Google drive for restful api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-drive-api, passport.js

I am using the 'passport-google-drive' and 'passport.js' libraries in NodeJS and My goal is to list all the files and folder and also to be able to download and upload files to drive.I'm able to 0auth user with google drive and after that i'm getting acessToken, profile of the user.
After that what is next Step to do? How to use acessToken and profile of user to list all files and folder and be able to download upload files from drive.

```js
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleDriveStrategy = require('passport-google-drive').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Keys = require('../config/keys.js');
const User = mongoose.model('drive-users');
const prettyjson = require('prettyjson');


passport.use(
    new GoogleDriveStrategy(
     {
       clientID: Keys.DRIVE_CLIENT_ID,
       clientSecret: Keys.DRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET,
       callbackURL: '/auth/google-drive/callback',
       scope : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
      },
      (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        console.log(prettyjson.render(profile));
        //what next????
          }
       )
   );
   //==================
   //routes
   //==================
   
   
   app.get(
    '/auth/google-drive',
     passport.authenticate('google-drive')
   );

  app.get(
    '/auth/google-drive/callback',
     passport.authenticate('google-drive')
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below shows how to use profile information to provide users with personalized functionality.

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleDriveStrategy = require('passport-google-drive').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Keys = require('../config/keys.js');
const User = mongoose.model('drive-users');
const prettyjson = require('prettyjson');

function extractProfile (profile) {
    let imageUrl = '';
    if (profile.photos && profile.photos.length) {
      imageUrl = profile.photos[0].value;
    }
    return {
      id: profile.id,
      displayName: profile.displayName,
      image: imageUrl
    };
  }

passport.use(
    new GoogleDriveStrategy(
     {
       clientID: Keys.DRIVE_CLIENT_ID,
       clientSecret: Keys.DRIVE_CLIENT_SECRET,
       callbackURL: '/auth/google-drive/callback',
       scope : 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
      },
      (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        console.log(prettyjson.render(profile));
          // Extract the minimal profile information we need from the profile object
          // provided by Google
          done(null, extractProfile(profile));
          }
       )
   );

    // Typically, this will be as simple as storing the user ID when serializing, and finding
    //  the user by ID when deserializing.
    passport.serializeUser( function (user, done) {
        done(null, user);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser( function (obj, done) {
        done(null, obj);
    });

   //==================
   // add your routes here
   //==================


   app.get(
    '/auth/google-drive',
     passport.authenticate('google-drive')
   );

  app.get(
    '/auth/google-drive/callback',
     passport.authenticate('google-drive')
   );
```

There's another [sample](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/authenticate-users) that uses Passport.js. This will help you to understand authentications of users using Passport.js library.

You can also read the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs) of Node.js using Google Drive for Resful API.